# Passing a struct as a pointer, resulting in a corrupted array?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct being passed in as a void* pointer

```
void *find_queens(void *args) {
```

I tried to turn this pointer in a usable struct using this

```
struct queens_arg *data = (struct queens_arg *) args;
```

However, the array that is stored within this

```
struct queens_arg {
  int board[64]; 
  int focus_idx;
};
```

called board is now being corrupted and does not reflect the original values, does anyone knows why? Thanks!

More information here:

This is the start of the function:

```
void *find_queens(void *args) {  

  //vars
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;
  struct queens_arg *data = (struct queens_arg *) args;
  int board[64];
  copy_array(data->board, board);
  print_board(data->board);
```

This is how it is called:

```
int board[64] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  };

  struct queens_arg *args = malloc(sizeof (struct queens_arg));
  args->focus_idx = 0;
  copy_array(board,args->board);
  (*find_queens)(&args);
```

When I print the array, I get this instead:

```
39456784 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Instead of 0 all the way. Which is weird.

Comment: Difficult to help with so little information. Can you post a working example, that shows the problem?

Comment: sorry bout that, made an edit

Comment: Are these operations in the same thread?

Comment: Why do you allocate 64x4 bytes to hold 64 bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that what you're passing in to the function is a `struct queens_arg**`, not a `struct queens_arg*`.  Notice that you're passing in a pointer to the pointer here:

```
(*find_queens)(&args);
```

When you try typecasting it here:

```
struct queens_arg *data = (struct queens_arg *) args;
```

You're converting a `struct queens_arg**` to a `struct queens_arg*`, which isn't a meaningful conversion.  You'll end up reading data near the pointer as though it were a `struct queens_arg`, which isn't what you want.

To fix this, just pass in the `args` pointer by itself, rather than a pointer to the `args` pointer:

```
(*find_queens)(args);
```

Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you're taking in a `void*` instead of a `struct queens_arg*`?  Part of the problem is that the compiler can't diagnose the nonsensical cast because you're funneling everything through `void*` first.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a pointer to a struct to a *void and back is perfectly legal even according to the C standard, to that is unlikely to be the problem. Are you certain the pointer really starts out as a pointer to your struct queens_arg?